# n8n on qnap ts 233 NAS Container Station node.js not working

Tags: node.js, nas, qnap, n8n

I try to get n8n running for creating flows on my qnap NAS.
Can someone tell me how to get it working? I typed in "npx n8n" but it only shows me "pm WARN deprecated". I got it running on my macbook without any issues.

Thanks for any manual or hint how I get it working!
Regards
Chris

Installed node.js as container, clicked on "execute" and "/bin/sh" and there I tried to use the command "npx n8n"